# addAccountExplicitly Success, but not showing any account in Settings/Account

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have written some code to add my custom account in settings
While clicking add account I can see my custom account and when clicking on that I am showing the sign in form. Inside that I am calling the below code

```
if (mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, userData)) {
        // worked
        System.out.println("Account added");
    } else {
        // guess not
        System.out.println("NOT DONE");
    }
```

First time it shows "Account added", but cant see anything in Settings/Accounts.
PLease anyone help me.

Here is the complete code

```
Log.d("AuthenticatorActivity", "onCreate");

    mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());

    String accountName = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME);
    mAuthTokenType = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_AUTH_TYPE);

    if (mAuthTokenType == null)
        mAuthTokenType = AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS;

    accountName= "test55";

    findAccount(accountName);

    System.out.println(mAuthTokenType + "accountName : " + accountName);

    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
    data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, mAuthTokenType);
    data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authtoken);
    data.putString(PARAM_USER_PASS, password);

    Bundle userData = new Bundle();
    userData.putString("userObjectId", "2");
    data.putBundle(AccountManager.KEY_USERDATA, userData);

    final Intent res = new Intent();
    res.putExtras(data);

    final Account account = new Account(accountName, "com.coderzheaven.auth_example");

    if (mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, userData)) {
        // worked
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } else {
        // guess not
        System.out.println("NOT DONE");
    }

    mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, userData);
    mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, mAuthTokenType, authtoken);
    setAccountAuthenticatorResult(data);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, res);
```

Comment: your sign-in form should be a subclass of `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` otherwise it won't be displayed on Settings

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and found that when the android:label field in authenticator.xml (or whatever xml file you are pointing to in your authenticator service definition in AndroidManifest.xml) doesn't contain a localized string that the account does not show up under Settings.

ie, this doesn't work:
android:label="My App"

but this does:
android:label="@string/my_app"

Comment: Thanks man, that really works, and that is so stupid, cost me a working day... Not a single word about that issue in android docs!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're sending the wrong value for the account type. The value needs to match android:accountType in your authenticator.xml.

data.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, **mAuthTokenType**);

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you correctly filled up data about your SyncService and SyncAdapter in AndroidManifest file. This helped for me.

This one in manifest:

```
<service android:name=".Model.Sync.SyncService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

And this one in syncadapter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:contentAuthority="com.example.android.datasync.provider"
   android:accountType="example.com"
   android:userVisible="true"
   android:supportsUploading="true"
   android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
   android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```